# Write output line in standard output in Erlang

Tags: erlang, stdout

I would like to know if there is any function in Erlang for writing

```
io:format("An output line~n").
```

in the standard output, without having to write `~n` every time, i.e. an equivalent to Java's

```
System.out.println("An output line");
```

I mean an already existing Erlang function. I know if it doesn't exist what I should do is creating my own function for that:

```
write_output(Text) ->
    io:format("~p~n", [Text]).
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is not, but writing one yourself is pretty simple:

```
myf(FS, Opts) ->
    io:format(FS, Opts),
    io:nl().
```

Answer (score 0):

Today, IODevice command is optional for io operations.

```
io:write(["~cmd1~cmd2",]T)
```

format, read & write can all be used in one line. as..

```
io:format(T);
% or
io:write(T);
```

but if there is a need for the line feed, the author's original code is more accurate

```
io:format("~p~n",[Number])
```

if building a function other built-in functions may be used to do the same

```
io:format(string:concat(integer_to_list(Number),"\n"))
```